# Flash fullscreen when loads

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

Im using adobe flash / AS3 
This animation will be used as a autorun splash screen
**how to do swf to be fullscren on load?**

where to write this on_load event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works in a projector with a simple delay on the fullscreen initiation.

I used that method:

```
function whatever(constructorOrOther:One)
{
    setTimeout(setToFullScreen, 1);
}

function setToFullScreen()
{
    stage.displayState = StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN_INTERACTIVE;
    stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.SHOW_ALL;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this for flash player (in browser)? Like the documentation says, you can only go into fullscreen as a result of a mouse click or keyboard input ( http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Stage.html#displayState ).

> Full-screen mode is initiated in response to a mouse click or key press by the user; the movie cannot change `Stage.displayState` without user input. Flash runtimes restrict keyboard input in full-screen mode. Acceptable keys include keyboard shortcuts that terminate full-screen mode and non-printing keys such as arrows, <kbd>Space</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>, and <kbd>Tab</kbd> keys. (Use full-screen interactive mode to support input from additional keys.) Keyboard shortcuts that terminate full-screen mode are: <kbd>Escape</kbd> (Windows, Linux, and Mac), <kbd>Control</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (Windows), <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd> (Mac), and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>.

Comment: Thank you Jonatan for you reply, but i will use it as Projector file (exe of swf) in CD autorun, You can help me with form_load or smt_load event where to write.

Comment: Projectors work the same way, so no automatic fullscreen mode. You might be able to do it with an AIR app though.